# Display image in JTable

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I want to display image in `JTable` from database.
I am using this for defaultTableModel.

This is global variable defined here:

```
byte[] image;
public ImageIcon getImage(){
return new ImageIcon(new      

ImageIcon(image).getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100, java.awt.SCALE_SMOOTH)):
    }action performd button here
    DefaultTableModel dt=new DefaultTableModel();
    dt.addColumn("ID");
    dt.addColumn("Image");
    query And conection manage here, 
    then while(rs.next()){
    String Id=rs.getString(1);
    image=rs.getBytes(2);
    Object[] obj={id,image};
    addRow(obj);
    tablename.setModel(dt);
```

but not working can any one tell me the solution?

Comment: "*not working*" is not an acceptable problem description

Comment: means nothing showing

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your implementation of `getColumnClass()`.